# Understanding the realtime api of Instagram - node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, instagram

i followed the instructions on [Instagram-Developers-Site](http://instagram.com/developer/realtime/) step-by-step and managed to subscribe to a hashtag. Now, when my node.js server is up and running i promt `req.body` to see what i am getting. These are the POST-Requests Instagram is sending me:

```
[ { changed_aspect: 'media', 
subscription_id: 2844823, 
object: 'tag', 
object_id: 'food', 
time: 1359561407 } ]
```

This is also as described in the guideline, my question now is:
What can i do with it?
I mean i expected a JSON-Object containing all necessary data to display a photo on my page.
Parameters for example would be: Name, PicURL, Comments, Location, but all i get is this above.
So can you tell me in which way this information I am receiving is usefull?

So a short summary:
- I want to display photos of a certain tag on my page
- using Node and Express
- PubSub is working
- I receive that there is a new picture postet but where do i get information about that particular picture?

Comment: You could use that information with the endpoints descibed in [tag endpoints](http://instagram.com/developer/endpoints/tags/)

Comment: Okay, but do i use ANY of the received data. Or is this "Realtime"-Api just for notifying me that there was a photo posted with that tag?
This is the point I am not understanding...

Comment: You get information about the type of object (tag) and its name (food) which you can use to call other API functions.

Comment: Yeah, so i can tell that there was infact a picture posted that was tagged as #food at that certain time. BUT i don't get any information about that picture and i can clearly not say what url this picture has. Am I right?

Comment: Agreed, that is also how I read the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

This JSON is only a notification that there is a new photo. Then you have to do a request with the instagram api for get the last photo.

```
api.instagram.com/v1/tags/[your tag]/media/recent?count=1&.....
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check this Instagram Real-time API Demo App to get inspiration: https://github.com/Instagram/Realtime-Demo